# How would I call a surface of equal energy?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

There are already several terms I know to denote surfaces on which a certain quantity is constant:

- equipotential surface: a surface of equal potential energy
- isobaric surface: a surface of equal pressure

How would I denote a surface of equal energy without falling back on *equi-energy surface*?

Comment: If you know *isobaric*, what's wrong with *isothermic*? Voting to close as general reference.

Comment: I need a more general term, _isothermic_ to me denotes surfaces with equal temperature, energy can come in other forms than temperature (I'm working on quantum mechanic energy densities). Why exactly are you voting to close? I haven't really read the term for this stack site, but since the `single-word-requests` tag exist I thought I could request a single word no?

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a perfectly good question. *Isothermic* means something completely different from what the OP is looking for, and the answer doesn't seem that easily searchable.

Comment: I'm no physicist, but I thought "heat" and "energy" were effectively equivalent at the technical level. Anyway, if OP wants an even more specialised term then I'd still have voted to close on the grounds that it's "too localised". We can "invent" terminology here, but if this concept is consistently meaningfu to specialists they probably already have their own word - which I don't think ELU should be concerned with identifying.

Comment: It looks like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: Heat is just another form of energy. Magneteic energy, for example, has nothing to do with temperature, and although all forms of energy can be changed into one another, I would feel awkward if talking about _isothermic surfaces_ when the subject is on _magnetic energy_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wiktionary lists *[isoenergetic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isoenergetic)* as "Having the same, or constant, energy".  You might peripherally introduce a definition,  *e.g.* "... the diagram illustrates quantum-mechanical energy isosurfaces, or *isoenergy surfaces* ...".

The terms *[isoline](http://en.mimi.hu/meteorology/isoline.html)* and *[isosurface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosurface)* are used generically for 2D and 3D equal-quantity cases, respectively.  After a phrase like "... the diagram illustrates quantum-mechanical energy isosurfaces ..." has introduced your terminology, references thereafter to *isosurfaces* would be understood as isoenergetic surfaces.

If only certain units of energy are used in the particular problem, tack *iso* on the front and see if it works.  That seems to be what was done for *[isobel](http://www.sfu.ca/sonic-studio/handbook/Isobel.html)*.

Answer (score 4):

Look up the etymology of ***energy***. It's Greek: **ἐνέργεια**. The rule is to use a Greek prefix with a Greek root, so you want Gk *iso-* rather than Latin *equi-* to mean "equal".

Putting *iso-* and *energeia* together and adding a little ordinary derivational morphology gives *isoenergetic*, which should work in context.